# Separating values added to state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking in multiple values in my web app from different users and currently they are all being displayed with no separation when the getVotes and message are rendered.  New to React, how would I add the line breaks?  Is that done in the render or state?  If you need more context with my code please let me know.  Thanks for your help!

```
 class App extends Component {
      state = {
        commissioner: '',
        members: [],
        getVotes: '',
        castedVotes: [],
        data: '',
        message: ''
      };

      async componentDidMount() {
        const commissioner = await fantasy.methods.commissioner().call();
        const members = await fantasy.methods.getMembers().call();
        const getVotes = await fantasy.methods.getVotes().call();

        this.setState({ commissioner, members, getVotes });
        this.setState({ number: this.value })
      }

    onSubmit = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      console.log(accounts)
      const data = await this.state.data

      this.setState({ message: 'waiting on vote to be secured on the blockchain'})

      await fantasy.methods.vote(data).send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: '3000000',
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.10', 'ether'),
        data: this.state.data
      });

      this.setState({ message: 'your vote has been cast '});
    };

    onClick = async () => {

      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const members = await this.state.members
      this.setState({ message: 'Reading the blockchain to see who has voted' });

      await fantasy.methods.getMembers().call({
        from: accounts[0]
      });

      this.setState({ message: members })

    };

    onCheck = async () => {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const getVotes = this.state.getVotes;

      this.setState({ message: 'Getting the votes from the blockchain' });

      await fantasy.methods.getVotes().call({
        from: accounts[0]
      });

      this.setState({ message: getVotes });

    };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>How many teams should we have in our league?</h2>
            <p>The commisssioner managing this contract is {this.state.commissioner}.  
            There are currently {this.state.members.length} votes
            </p>

            <hr />

            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h4>Cast your vote and be heard!</h4>
              <div>
                <label>Max Teams:</label>
                <input 
                  data={this.state.data}
                  onChange={event => this.setState({ data: event.target.value })}
                />

              </div>
              <button>VOTE</button>
              </form>

             <hr />

              <h4>Who has voted?</h4>
              <button onClick={this.onClick}>See Members</button>

              <hr />

              <h4>What are the votes?</h4>
              <button onClick={this.onCheck}>See Votes</button>



             <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>

          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by separation? Could you include a screenshot of what it looks like right now? Is this actually a react issue, or are you looking for a CSS solution?

Comment: What kinda linebreak?? Where do you want the linebreak??

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions guys.  I would be open to using a CSS solution if that is easier.  I thought it would be react related because I am taking in multiple values and storing them in an array in State.  As far as linebreak, I want it to separate the addresses one on top of each other as well as the votes.  Any ideas?